# Priority Due Date column sharepoint online

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to setup a Due Date calculated column on an SPO list and whilst I've managed to work out the formula for days, I cant quite work out hours?!

I have SLA priorities on my list as per the below:

5= 365 days

4= 5 days

3= 5 days

2= 1 day

1= 8 hours

=IF(Priority="5",Created+365,IF(Priority="4",Created+5,IF(Priority="3",Created+5,IF(Priority="2",Created+1,IF(Priority="1",Created+0.8)))))

Someone suggested I try the below however I receive an invalid syntax error:

**=IF(Priority="5", addDays(Created, 365), IF(Priority="4", addDays(Created, 5), IF(Priority="3", addDays(Created, 5), IF(Priority="2", addDays(Created,1),IF(Priority="1", addHours(Created,8))))))**

Answer (score 0):

My test worked for the following:

Adding hours to a date field: **[Created]+(8/24)**

```
=IF(Priority="5",Created+365,IF(Priority="4",Created+5,IF(Priority="3",Created+5,IF(Priority="2",Created+1,IF(Priority="1",Created+(8/24)))))
```

[image]